# Gallery Layout through posts

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I am developing a  gallery in which I want a layout something like .. http://mightymente.org/projects/aarohievents/design/

I developed most of it .. please review the code and give suggestions how to impprove it.

My code:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query("showposts=6&cat=1&orderby=asc");
$count = 1; 
while ( $the_query ->have_posts() ) {$the_query ->the_post(); $i++;
    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'thumbnail-size',     
   false); 
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($thumb_url[0]);  
    if($width == 800){ 
        $class='grid-1';
    } elseif($width==270) { 
        $class='sub_grid gallery_w3l';
    }   
    if ($i == 1){
        echo "<div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 grid_w3'>";
    }
?>

    <div class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
    <a class="cm-overlay" href="<?php echo $thumb_url[0];?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $thumb_url[0];?>" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
    <div class="w3agile-text w3agile-text-small">
    <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
    </div>
     </a> <?php //echo $i ; ?>
     </div>
<?php 
    $count++; 
    if ($i == 3){
        echo "</div><div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 grid_w3'>";}
        if ($i == 6){
            echo "</div>";$i=0;
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: inside of the if ($i ==3 ) you nested an if with ($i == 6), this code wil never be executed. Move it outside.

Comment: I didnt get it .

Comment: or better you use condition `if ($i % 3 == 0)`

Comment: don't add unless code only keep width auto, and see result

Comment: I want two different width for gallery

Answer (score 0):

This is your actuall code:

```
   if ($i == 3){
       //At this position $i has to be 3, if not it will never come to here
       echo "</div><div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 grid_w3'>";
       if ($i == 6){
          //So this line will never be executed cause $i will never be 6 here
          echo "</div>";$i=0;
       }
    }
```

So it should be:

```
    if ($i == 3){
       echo "</div><div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 grid_w3'>";
    }
    if ($i == 6){
       echo "</div>";$i=0;
    }
```

Or with elseIf

Based on  @ravisachaniya comment you can also go for

```
if ($i % 3 == 0){
     //This way it divides $i with 3 and if the levtover is 0 it goes inside
     //Means 3, 6, 9, 12, 15 and so on
     echo "</div><div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 grid_w3'>";
     if ($i == 6){
          echo "</div>";$i=0;
     }
 }
```

With this solution it would also print in the 6th loop

```
echo "</div><div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 grid_w3'>";
```